# Does declaring a variable count towards big O notation?

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

Lets say in Java I declare a new variable:
int k = 0;
Will this count towards the O notation, or do I ignore it for the O notation?

Comment: It won't affect it.

Comment: It depends on how many times you call that statement. If only once, you can ignore it (it will contribute O(1) time to the overall time).

Comment: eran: If we are just talking about assigning, I would consider it as empty statement (does not have any effect). But here we are on thin ice of theory vs compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big O notation ignores the constants.

```
int k = 0;
```

is a single constant variable(in terms of memory).

But following loop would have  `O(n)` complexity

```
for(int k=0;k<n;k++){}
```

As it would run `k++` `n` times.

Comment: What if it was declared inside a loop?

Comment: Then it would have some complexity. I have added the note. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable like this shouldn't:

```
int k;
```

Assigning to it like this would:

```
k = 0;
```

Initialization like this would do both, so it would count:

```
int k = 0;
```

Note that even the last one will only contribute a constant factor (which will get ignored), unless it's executed in some loop.

Comment: Does returning a variable from a method count towards o notation?

Answer (score 1):

O notation is used for measuring the complexity of code. That means number of statements it executes. If you are using a nested loop one loop inside another loop, in that case complexity is O(n^2) because each iteration corresponds to one n and since one loop is inside another loop n^2 can be related. However your code is simply initializing a variable, so it can be thought of O(1) complexity since it gets executed in constant time. However if there was any computation that was required to provide any value to variable then the complexity of that computation should be taken into consideration.

Hope this helps :)