# What is the Big O Notation (Time Complexity) of an array declaration?

Tags: big-o

I was wondering what the time complexity for this line would be in Big O notation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
```

Sorry if this is a super easy question I'm fairly new to Big O notation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977916/does-declaring-a-variable-count-towards-big-o-notation

Comment: I think it depends on the underlying memory allocator. If it uses a simple pointer to the next available memory region, the complexity could be `O(1)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does declaring a variable count towards big O notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977916/does-declaring-a-variable-count-towards-big-o-notation)

Comment: @Progman that question is not a duplicate, because variable declaration is a totally different thing to instantiating an array.

Comment: @ForceBru In Java it is definitely O(n), because the array has to be filled with a default value when it is created.

Comment: Some languages also perform an *initialization* when you declare an array. This is a more crucial operation in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! That makes a lot of sense. So would it be O(n)?